# Can't modify file in external storage in android

Tags: android, android-external-storage

Please help me... I'm getting

> java.io.FileNotFoundException : /storage/'my external storage'/Music/'file name' :  open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

when I'm modifying music's id3 tags which are located in my sd card with jaudiotagger.

I already wrote read/write permissions on manifest file, and I wrote requesting  method, permission request result callback method, and a part that modify tags when button clicked like this.

```
private void requestExternalStoragePermissions() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted to write your External storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            start();
        }
        else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }
    }

}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1 : {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0&&grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                start();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied to access your External storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}

savebutton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            try{
                AudioFile f = AudioFileIO.read(file);
                Tag tag = f.getTag();
                tag.setField(FieldKey.TITLE,editText1.getText().toString());
                tag.setField(FieldKey.ALBUM,editText2.getText().toString());
                tag.setField(FieldKey.ARTIST,editText3.getText().toString());
                tag.setField(FieldKey.ALBUM_ARTIST,editText4.getText().toString());
                tag.setField(FieldKey.YEAR,editText5.getText().toString());
                tag.setField(FieldKey.DISC_NO,editText6.getText().toString());
                tag.setField(FieldKey.TRACK,editText7.getText().toString());
                tag.setField(FieldKey.LYRICS,editText8.getText().toString());
                f.commit();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tag Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is the file on a sd card?

Comment: Can you please show how are you modifying the file

Comment: @the_dani The file is on my sd card.

Comment: @RatishBansal I'm using Jaudiotagger to modify id3 tags.

Comment: @RatishBansal I added code.

Comment: Are you sure the path to the file is correct? It does say `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: `/storage/'my external storage'/Music/'file name'` does not look alike a path ...

Comment: AudioFile f = AudioFileIO.read(file); Can you please show the code from where this file is comming. Also can you please try once by removing if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) // this check.

Comment: @TheGamer007 I already open the file that is in the path

Comment: @MartinZeitler 'my external storage' means my sd card's name and Music folder is the folder that I made for saving my musics. And 'file name' means any music's file name..

Comment: @RatishBansal I used cursor to find music files from all storage. About path, I used    `cursor.getString(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)`. And If I remove that code, I can't use `checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)`..

Answer (score 0):

In Android 4.4 and higher, editing files on the sd card is not possible anymore. I had the same issue..

The only workaround is to copy the file to the internal storage, modify it and move it back.

Comment: I didn't tried that, but I think if I can't modify my way,moving it back wouldn't works..